# Mixing PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

Working on the same page as before,but now I'm using it as a playground for messing around with jQuery so I can learn it for my'boss.' Unfortunately, I can't get the javascript in this file to execute, let alone give me a warning. All of the PHP and HTML on the page work perfectly, it's just the script that's the issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

  if( isset($_POST['mushu']) )
  {
    playAnimation();
    clickInc();
  }

  function playAnimation()
  {
     echo "<img src='cocktail-kitten.jpg' id='blur'>";
  }

  function clickInc()
  {
    $count = glob("click*.txt");

    $clicks = file($count[0]);
    $clicks[0]+=1;

    $fp = fopen($count[0], "w") or die("Can't open file");
    fputs($fp, $clicks[0]);
    fclose($fp);

    echo $clicks[0];

  }
?>

<html>

  <head>

    <title>Adobe Kitten</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
          method="post">
    <input type="submit"
           value="Let's see what Mushu is up to."
           name="mushu">
    </form>

    <script>
      $(document).ready( function()
      {
        $('#blur').click( function()
        {
          $(this).blur( function()
          {
            alert('Handler for .blur() called.');
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `playAnimation()` before your `<html>` tag, so your html is malformed. JQuery probably can't find the `#blur` element because it's not actually inside your web page, much less within the `<body>`.

Move the `if( isset($_POST['mushu'])) ...` block of code somewhere after the body tag.

Comment: Okay, so I moved the php to after the body tag but before the `</html>` and still nothing happens. Am I formatting the jQuery incorrectly?

Comment: Your jquery is odd - you've set it up so that clicking the image will set the blur() function on the image. Why don't you first try making the click() function alert something so you can see it working.

Answer (score 1):

Check FireBug's console, or FireFox' Error Console.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that jquery.js is being included, and check your error console.

Otherwise, a few obvious errors which may or may not contribute to your javascript problems:

- You're outputting HTML in `playAnimation()` before your opening HTML tag
- Your form's action attribute is blank - you need `<?=` or `<?php echo`
- Your script tags should read `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott said you need to echo the div in the actual body of the page. Also, I think another problem you have is you're calling .blur which is the event when your mouse leaves the image. Since you have functions like animate I think you might actually be looking for .fade http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/. Try something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function()
    {
        $('#blur').click( function()
        {
            $(this).fadeOut('slow', function()
            {
                alert('All Done');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```